# Cholesky factorization function from Matlab to C

Tags: c, matlab

I tried to convert a Matlab loop performing cholesky factorization to C. I got correct results just for the first column.

The Matlab code:

```
M = [5 1.2 0.3 -0.6; 1.2 6 -0.4 0.9; 0.3 -0.4 8 1.7; -0.6 0.9 1.7 10];
n = length( M );
L = zeros( n, n );
for i=1:n
    L(i, i) = sqrt( M(i, i) - L(i, :)*L(i, :)' );

    for j=(i + 1):n
        L(j, i) = ( M(j, i) - L(i, :)*L(j, :)' )/L(i, i);
    end
end
```

My C code:

```
int  main()
{

    double M[4*4]={5, 1.2, 0.3, -0.6, 1.2, 6, -0.4, 0.9, 0.3, -0.4, 8, 1.7, -0.6, 0.9, 1.7, 10};
    int n=4;
    double L[4*4]={0};
    double sum;
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
        sum=0;
        for (int j=0;j<n;j++){
            sum+=L[i*n+j]*L[j*n+i];
            }
    L[i*n+i]=sqrt(M[i*n+i]-sum);

    for (int j=i+1;j<n;j++){
        sum=0;
        for(int k=0;k<n;k++){
            sum+=L[i*n+k]*L[k*n+j];
           }
        L[j*n+i]=(M[j*n+i]-sum)/L[i*n+i];

      }

}
 return 0;

}
```

The result in Matlab is:

```
L =

    2.2361         0         0         0
    0.5367    2.3900         0         0
    0.1342   -0.1975    2.8183         0
   -0.2683    0.4368    0.6466    3.0527
```

But in C the result is:

```
L_c =

    2.2361         0         0         0
    0.5367    2.4495         0         0
    0.1342   -0.1633    2.8284         0
   -0.2683    0.3674    0.6010    3.1623
```

Where is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the lines

```
sum+=L[i*n+j]*L[j*n+i];
```

and

```
sum+=L[i*n+k]*L[k*n+j];
```

I think this should be

```
sum+=L[i*n+j]*L[i*n+j];
```

and

```
sum+=L[i*n+k]*L[j*n+k];
```

respectively. The transpose in the Matlab code just changes the direction of the vector, but does not switch around the arguments or something.

I advise you to make a function that calculates the dot products, so you can reuse code.

Comment: I edited my answer. My bad for not seeing this immediately :)

Answer (score 1):

See the Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>    
#include <iostream> 
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

double M[4][4]={5, 1.2, 0.3, -0.6, 1.2, 6, -0.4, 0.9, 0.3, -0.4, 8, 1.7, -0.6, 0.9, 1.7, 10};
vector <vector<double> >L;
int n=4;
double calculateFunc1(int i){
double temp =0;
for (int t = 0; t < n; t ++)
    temp += L[i][t]*L[i][t];
return sqrt(M[i][i] - temp);
}

double calculateFunc2(int i,int j){
double temp =0;
for (int t = 0; t < n; t ++)
    temp += L[i][t]*L[j][t];
return (M[j][i] - temp) / L[i][i];
}

int  main()
{ 
 vector <double>temp;
for (int i =0; i < n; i ++){
    for(int j =0; j < n; j ++){
        temp.push_back(0.0);
    }
    L.push_back(temp);
    temp.clear();
}

for(int i =0; i < n; i ++){
    L[i][i] = calculateFunc1(i);

    for(int j= i +1 ; j < n; j++){
        L[j][i] = calculateFunc2(i,j);
    }
}


for (int i=0;i<n;i++){

    for (int j=0;j<n;j++){
        cout<< L[i][j]<<" ";
        }
    cout << "\n";
}
 return 0;
}
```